# How to assign a component to a Delphi GridPanel row and column programmatically?

Tags: delphi, controls, assign, tgridpanel

I am working on a project using Delphi where I am making rows and columns for a GridPanel dynamically.  I am also creating a panel (TPanel) that I intend to place in each cell dynamically.

My question is: **How do you assign the newly created panel to a particular cell that is in the GridPanel?**

I am guessing that I have to assign the panel's "Parent" property so that it is the GridView.  However, I have not been able to adjust a "Row" or "Column" property for the TPanel unlike when you able to when you assign a panel to the GridPanel using the design environment.

Comment: Do you mean TGridPanel layout? Firemonkey or VCL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do you assign the newly created panel to a particular cell that is
> in the GridPanel?

The answer is, you can't. Adding new components to the `TGridPanel`, wether at design time or programmatically, places the new component in the next unoccupied cell. By default, in left to right order.

The `ExpandStyle` property (`emAddRows` or `emAddColumns`) determines how the `TPanelGrid` is expanded when filled, and further controls are added.

After you have added the new panel (or other component) to the `TGridPanel` you may change its position as others have answered, by accessing the control via the `ControlCollection` property.

Comment: Thanks!  This makes sense and actually simplify things for what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
 TGridPanelLayout.ControlCollection[position].row := 0;
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the property

```
TGridPanelLayout.ControlCollection[index].row := 0;
```

and

```
TGridPanelLayout.ControlCollection[index].Column := 0;
```